# Failed to publish TcpConnectionOpenEvent Or TcpConnectionOpenEvent, Dispatcher failed to deliver Message

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tcp, spring-integration

In spring integration i am using event Listener to handle TcpConnectionOpenEvent or TcpConnectionCloseEvent.

When i use code blog below, i can handle connection open close application event but i am receiving Warning log like

> 2020-08-11 11:15:46.857  WARN 7104 --- [  XNIO-1 task-1] o.s.i.i.tcp.connection.TcpNetConnection  : Failed to publish TcpConnectionOpenEvent [SOME DETAIL] **OPENED**:Dispatcher failed to deliver Message; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException

```
@Bean
public MessageChannel connectionStatusChannel() {
    DirectChannel directChannel = new DirectChannel();
    directChannel.subscribe(new ServerConnectionStatusHandler());
    return directChannel;
}

@EventListener
public void listen(TcpConnectionOpenEvent event) {
    String eventName = "TcpConnectionOpenEvent";
    String destination = event.getConnectionFactoryName();
    connectionStatusChannel().send(new GenericMessage<>(eventName + "-" + destination));
}

@Component
public class ServerConnectionStatusHandler implements MessageHandler {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ServerConnectionStatusHandler.class);

    @Autowired
    private SimpMessageSendingOperations messagingTemplate;

    public ServerConnectionStatusHandler() {
    }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message<?> message) throws MessagingException {
        log.debug("ServerConnectionStatusHandler # handleMessage message : {} ", message.getPayload());
        messagingTemplate.convertAndSend("/topic/agent/connection/tracker", message.getPayload());
    }
}
```

This does not break my flow but i want to understand why i am taking this warnig and how can i clear it. Without @EventListener it disappers...

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can’t say `new` if you would like to get access to some bean in the application context.

I mean this:

```
directChannel.subscribe(new ServerConnectionStatusHandler());
```

So you create a non-managed instance if your class. Meanwhile you need to auto wire existing bean:

```
@Bean
public MessageChannel connectionStatusChannel(ServerConnectionStatusHandler handler) {
    DirectChannel directChannel = new DirectChannel();
    directChannel.subscribe(handler);
    return directChannel;
}
```

Comment: Hello Artem, thanks fo your response and yes now warning is cleared but also i need to understand reason of that warning. Is it because of just i create object by myself ?

Comment: Since you get an instance of that object not through Spring inversion of control container, but manually via plain `new` , no dependency injection happens into that object.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me in listen(...) event.getConnectionFactoryName() is null, or possibly connectionStatusHandler() is returning null

Comment: İn log lines, i can see connectionFactoryName... it may related something different...

Comment: This is not my area. Though it seems the event is called without a destination.